# Size explanation for apple On Demand Resource?

Tags: ios, on-demand-resources

As per apple documents total size on demand resource stored on app store for an app is no more than 20GB. But as resources are maintained version specific by apple, so this total size of 20GB is for all version or each version will have 20GB?

For example: I have uploaded app with version A having 5GB of resources on ODR. What will be the available storage size for next version for an app? It will be 15GB or 20GB?

Is there any option available to monitor On Demand Resource storage?